# Why is נַעֲרָ sometimes marked as a keri uketiv and sometimes not?

Tags: words, tanach, writing-printing

The word נַעֲרָה *na'arah* (girl, maiden, young lady) is almost uniformly spelled in the Torah in the form נַעֲרָ, without the concluding *heh*.

However, it seem that it is marked as an instance of *keri uketiv* only in some places, but not in others.

For example, the Leningrad Codex has [Devarim 22:15](https://tanach.us/Tanach.xml?Deut22:15) (emphasis mine):

> וְלָקַ֛ח אֲבִ֥י **הנער הַֽנַּעֲרָ֖ה** וְאִמָּ֑הּ וְהוֹצִ֜יאוּ אֶת־בְּתוּלֵ֧י **הנער הַֽנַּעֲרָ֛ה** אֶל־זִקְנֵ֥י הָעִ֖יר הַשָּֽׁעְרָה׃

marked as *keri uketiv* (along with other instances of the word in that and subsequent passages). (See [here](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/50/Leningrad-codex-05-deuteronomy.pdf#page=28) for a facsimile of the relevant page in the codex.)

However, when it comes to [Bereishit 24:16](https://tanach.us/Tanach.xml?Gen24:16) (and subsequent instances in that passage) we find (emphasis mine):

> **וְהַֽנַּעֲרָ֗** טֹבַ֤ת מַרְאֶה֙ מְאֹ֔ד בְּתוּלָ֕ה וְאִ֖ישׁ לֹ֣א יְדָעָ֑הּ וַתֵּ֣רֶד הָעַ֔יְנָה וַתְּמַלֵּ֥א כַדָּ֖הּ וַתָּֽעַל׃

without an indication that this is *keri uketiv*, even though the word is written and read the same as in Devarim. (See [here](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d4/Leningrad-codex-01-genesis.pdf#page=24) for a facsimile of the relevant page in the codex.)

What is the reason for this discrepancy?

Comment: Maybe it's only marked in places where you may get confused?

Comment: related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/61100/759