# לא vs לו and other homophones - what can we do to avoid unwanted meaning in our prayers

Tags: halacha, tefilla, pronunciation

There is a lot about pronouncing things correctly so we don't say the wrong thing, especially in tefilla. Eg in shema: we are to pronounce the ayin in "שמ**ע**" so it doesn't sound like "שמא"; "maybe", chas veshalom.

I have a two fold question. There are words that are homophones, and this can lead to unwanted meaning (eg כי יערב **לו** ידידותך), but we can't do anything about it. This actually applies to Ashkenazim with Shema as they generally pronounce ayin the same as aleph.

1. So what are we to do?
2. If nothing, then why are we so concerned about the ayin in shema?

This fear that we will end up saying something heretical - what is it based on? Surely the only fear about the ayin is from the general halacha of pronouncing the words of tefilla properly. We say many tefillot that are, in their homophonic meaning, heretical, and we don't have any issue with that (or do we?).

Comment: לא מאסתים ולא ג**ע**לתים

Comment: The best advice is probably for a person to study the prayers so that he will know what they actually mean when he says them. Alternatively, if you are praying from a siddur, you can see for yourself which word it is. In some places, there is a *k'ri/k'siv* that indicates both meanings, e.g. in *Mizmor l'soda* (*T'hillim* 100:3, "הוּא-עָשָׂנוּ ולא (וְלוֹ) אֲנַחְנוּ"). We belong to HaShem (וְלוֹ אֲנַחְנוּ), and we should not be so arrogant to feel that we are self-made (ולא אֲנַחְנוּ).

Comment: *Shir HaShirim Rabba* ([2:4](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%A8_%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%94_%D7%91_%D7%93)): ודגלו עלי אהבה. אמר ר' אחא: עם הארץ שקורא לאהבה איבה, כגון: ואהבת, ואייבת. אמר הקדוש ברוך הוא: ודילוגו עלי אהבה. How much more so is it not a problem if the person pronounces the word correctly.

Comment: I suppose you should exclude the א-ע pair, because one can learn to pronounce _ayin_ to avoid such ambiguity. Better example is the לא-לו pair which is identical according to all traditions. (It seemed to me that indeed א-ע caused the most trouble.)

Comment: True homophones are exceedingly rare in properly pronounced Hebrew

Comment: @DoubleAA the לא-לו pair is exceedingly common

Comment: Arguendo. Now find me another 3

Comment: @DoubleAA if the issue is as I am assuming, it would still apply even if there was a single homophonic pair, and it only happens once in all liturgy

Comment: Related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/61100/759

Comment: I didn't deny that one case was sufficient to ask from, though I find the question of why bother pronouncing anything correctly if sometimes homophones lead to ambiguity anyway far from compelling. By similar logic just say blahblahblah and know God understands what you intended.

Comment: @DoubleAA I appreciate that, I'm not sure that's what I am saying